# Word Spellcheck in VBscript for HTML content

Tags: vba, ms-word, spell-checking

I am using CKEditor as my WYSIWYG editor. I understand that it comes with some of spellchecking plugins. However - we choose word as the spell check engine. When We try to do the spell check, Word shows warnings on the HTML tags. If we remove the HTML tags, we loose the formatting. It has become either or. Can anyone suggest - how we can get HTML tags skipped from Word spell checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this thread, I used a Regular Expression to get the HTML tags out of the way. Before calling the Spellcheck method() - I will eliminate all the HTML tags and then pass the string to spell check. It worked for my scenario.